# How to calculate row x and row y if same column in table mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

How to calculate row 1 and row 4 same column.

My code :

```
$qR1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tbproduct WHERE nameproduct = '".$product."'");
while( $res1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qR1)){
    $qR2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tbvalproduct WHERE nameproduct = '".$res1['product']."' ");
    while($res2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qR2)){
        echo $res2['product']."=".$res2['value']."<br>";
    }

}
```

Output :

```
1.product1 = 1500000
2.product1 = 1400000
3.product1 = 1300000
4.product2 = 1000000
5.product2 = 900000
6.product2 = 800000
```

What I want:

```
-row 1 + row 4 // 1500000 + 1000000
-row 2 + row 5 // 1400000 + 900000
-row 3 + row 6 // 1300000 + 800000
```

Sample table :

```
Id      product       value
---------------------------    
1    product1       1500000
2    product1       1400000
3    product1        1300000
4    product2        1000000
5    product2         900000
6    product2         800000
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what are you looking for. What does mean row 1 and 3 same column?

Comment: Can you provide tables structure with data sample?

Comment: Im sorry..im first time this forum..so im confuse to ask..

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with just a single query:

```
SELECT t1.product, t1.value
FROM tbvalproduct t1
INNER JOIN tbproduct t2
    ON t1.nameproduct = t2.product
WHERE
    t2.nameproduct = ?;
```

Your updated PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT t1.product, t1.value FROM tbvalproduct t1 INNER JOIN tbproduct t2 ";
$sql .= "ON t1.nameproduct = t2.product WHERE t2.nameproduct = ?";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $product);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo $row['product']."=".$row['value']."<br>";
    }

   $stmt->free_result();
   $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: sorry sir i try to user ur code but i get notice warning * underfinned function prepare...

Comment: @wisnusetiyanto since this answer uses the OOP design pattern, you would need to replace `$mysqli->` with `$con->` to match your mysqli object from `mysqli_connect()` Otherwise adapt the [OOP design pattern to use procedural equivalent](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: sorry sir my mistake.. im get result..but this result like loop... how to im calculate example row 1 + row 4

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, but I think this is what you're looking for.

```
$sql = "SELECT p1.value 'tbproduct_value', p2.value 'tbvalproduct_value' 
    FROM tbproduct p1 join tbvalproduct p2 on p1.nameproduct = p2.nameproduct
    WHERE nameproduct = '".$product."'";

$q = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );
while( $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $q ) ){
    echo $res['product']."=".$res['tbproduct_value']. $res['tbvalproduct_value'] . "<br>";
}
```

Please keep us updated!

Cheers

Comment: Use prepared statements if at all possible.